# MySQL: How to LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL (user1 blocks user2 OR upside down)?

Tags: mysql, database, left-join

I have a table `user` and in addition `INNER JOIN` it with table `cities` and a few others already. Now I also have the following table:

```
blocked_user
--------------------------------------------------------
id | user1_id | user2_id | timestamp
```

How can I use `LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL`, so both user combinations (user1 blocked user2 or user2 blocked user1) are excluded from the search results?

```
user
--------------------------------------------------------
id | username | ...
```

Thank you very much in advance for you help!

Comment: What do `user1_id` and `user2_id` represent?  You should consider renaming those fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have a current user (the user who is performing the request) and you want to hide all users they have blocked or all users who have blocked them.  I'm also assuming that `user1_id` is the user who did the blocking, and `user2_id` is the user they blocked.  You should edit your question to make those points more clear.

If that's right, here's what I would do:

```
SELECT id, username

FROM user

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT user2_id AS blockee_id
    FROM blocked_user
    WHERE user1_id = :current_user_id
) this_user_blocked
ON user.id = this_user_blocked.blockee_id

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT user1_id AS blocker_id
    FROM blocked_user
    WHERE user2_id = :current_user_id
) blocked_this_user
ON user.id = blocked_this_user.blocker_id

WHERE this_user_blocked.blockee_id IS NULL
AND blocked_this_user.blocker_id IS NULL
```

I think it makes sense to use two separate `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ... IS NULL` constructs because you are really checking for two different situations.

Comment: Hi jnylen! Thank you very very much for your help. Unfortunately I get an error `#1054 - Unknown column '2' in 'group statement'`?

Comment: Updated to fix that error and that comment about separate joins.

Comment: wow, thank you so much jnylen! it is working like charm... so fast despite millions of rows in both tables! thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

In this case I guess the keyword NOT EXISTS would be adecuate, semantically at least.

```
SELECT * FROM user u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM blocked_user b 
    WHERE 
        b.user1_id = u.id 
    OR  b.user2_id = u.id
)
```

There's also indeed the option of using:

```
SELECT * FROM user u LEFT JOIN blocked_user b ON b.user1_id = u.id 
                                              OR b.user2_id = u.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

But regarding to the performances I don't know which one is more efficient.

rgds.